# Add an Object with a List of Objects to a List

Tags: c#, wpf, object, observablecollection

I've got a bit of a problem trying to add an object to a list. I am working in c#.

**Object with List of Objects:**

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Names> FullNames { get; set; }
}
```

*Names* **Object**

```
public class Names
{
    string First { get; set; }
    string Middle { get; set; }
    string Last { get; set; }

    public Names(string First, string Middle, string Last)
    {
        this.First = First;
        this.Middle = Middle;
        this.Last = Last;
    }
}
```

**The Problem Area:**

In the MainWindow, I create an Observable Collection of type Person. How do you correctly implement adding the *FullNames* list? I haven't been able to make it work at all.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public ObservableCollection<Person> people { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        people.Add(new Person() { Title = "President", FullNames = new Names(First = "George", Middle = "K", Last = "Will")}); //problem area
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to add a `TodoItem` to an `ObservableCollection<Person>` - what would that even mean?

Comment: "TodoItem" was not what i meant, sorry -- I just edited "TodoItem" to "Person".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Initialize people list first.
2. You can only add Person object in your collection.
3. Names should be initialized to list.
4. Constructor call with arguments is not correct.

Instead of `First = "George"`, it should be `First : "George"` or simply omit the arguments name altogether if passing in same order as in definition.

---

This should work:

```
people.Add(new Person() { Title = "President",
                          FullNames = new List<Names>()
                              { new Names("George", "K", "Will") } });
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright, a few things.

1. You've got a `NullReferenceException` waiting to happen. `people` is initialized as null, and you're adding directly to it without giving it an instance.
2. You have a collection containing `Person` objects, and you're adding a `TodoItem` to it. One of those is wrong.
3. Your real question, you need to use the `List` initializer on the `FullNames` property, because it *looks* like you're trying to set a `List<T> = T`, which doesn't make any sense.
4. You are calling a constructor of `Names` with `=`, which is bad syntax. You want to leave out the parameter names. As @RohitVats points out, you could also use `:` to specify, but here you really don't want to. A constructor is really just a method call, so the same syntax rules applies to them as any other function (for the most part).

To address these concerns, your code would look something like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    people.Add(new Person()
               {
                   Title = "President",
                   FullNames = new List<Names>()
                               {
                                   new Names("George", "K", "Will")
                               }
               });
}
```

For the sake of making sure you understand what's going on here, this would be the same as writing:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    Person toAdd = new Person();
    toAdd.Title = "President";
    toAdd.FullNames = new List<Names>();
    toAdd.FullNames.Add(new Names("George", "K", "Will"));
    people.Add(toAdd);
}
```

*This one isn't a bug, but you should really consider adjusting your `Names` type name to be something singular, even just `FullName`, because it's hard to read as it stands. I get where you're coming from, since there are in fact multiple names (first, middle, and last), but it's still confusing.*

Comment: Incorrect syntax in constructor arguments. This won't compile.